# Provable security: impossible reduction when messages are encrypted/semantic security with function depending on the output of adversary

Tags: provable-security, reduction

I've a problem with a protocol for which I can prove the security if the messages sent by the adversary are sent in clear, but I can't prove the security anymore if the messages sent by the adversary are encrypted... and this is a bit strange since I expect the protocol to also be secure in that second case.

More precisely, I'm considering a protocol for which a server Bob receives a message $k$ from Alice (this can be seen as an encryption of a bit string $d_0$ under the secret public key $t_k$) and sends back a message $y$ (which can also be seen as an encryption of some messages $x$ under the **same public key** $k$ of Alice: not that due to the shape of the protocol I really need to use this exact same key). In the security proof, I'd like to show that no malicious Bob can find a secret value $\theta_\pi=f(x,d_0)$ that should look random otherwise.

The good news is that if I know $x$, I can invert $f$ and find $d_0$. Therefore if a malicious Bob knows $x$, I could do a reduction to prove that if Bob can find $\theta_\pi$ they Bob also knows $d_0 = f^{-1}(x,\theta_\pi)$: this is a contradiction since the encryption is IND-CPA secure.

Unfortunately, this reduction does not work because the malicious Bob may not "know" $x$: they only send an encrypted version $y$ of it: and during the reduction I can't decrypt this $y$ since the key is only known to Alice (this is unavoidable in my case)...

Is there some methods to still prove security in that case? I guess **I need something like semantic security** but where the function that is computed is not efficiently computable (this is already the case in the current definition) and also **depends on some outputs of the adversary**.

**EDIT**

To answer to Mikero, I think that in your argument we need to say something like that:

[image]

If we manage to get the right box, then I agree that the proof follows easily. But I'm not sure how to prove the equivalence between these two scenarios. I don't think this is a direct reduction to IND-CPA security, because the distinguisher also has access to $\theta_\pi$ which is linked with some information about a decoding of $y$. I guess it would also be nice to show that the first diagram is equivalent to

[image]

but not sure how to prove that (of course $Ideal Func_1$ is distinguishable from $Ideal Func_3$, the question is when we add the simulator on top).

Comment: It sounds like Alice is honest in this situation, so the simulator should generate Alice's public key. Then the simulator would be able to decrypt ciphertexts encrypted under that public key and do your usual reduction. BTW, what happens if Bob simply echoes back the same encryption of $d_0$?

Comment: Alternatively, the standard way to ensure that the adversary knows the plaintext would be to add a proof of knowledge to the ciphertext.

Comment: @Maeher Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this cannot work in my case because I'm in a quantum setting: basically, for the adversary to learn $x$, it needs to destroy its state (and then, the protocol is not useful anymore). I could of course do a "cut and choose" approach by asking from time to time do destroy the state and from time to time to continue, but then I only get polynomial security :-( I also don't think that the approach proposed by Mikero works, I'll try to ellaborate in another message.

Comment: @Mikero Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure if it works (at least in my case). If the simulator picks the public key of Alice, we need an argument to say that the simulator can encrypt a random $d_0'$ in place of $d_0$ (because $d_0$ should not leak to the simulator) without being detected. However, I don't think this is directly implies by IND-CPA (see my edit). Am I missing something?

Comment: @Mikero also, if Bob echos back $y$, then it would basically set $x = 00$ (which is perfectly fine).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how the quantum setting is an issue. Are you saying that y is in fact *not* a ciphertext, but an arbitrary superposition of ciphertexts? First, why would you allow the adversary to do that? And second, then as far as I can see you can just as well compute the proof of knowledge on that superposition.

Comment: @Maeher It's because the goal of the protocol is to create a quantum state unknown to Bob. Basically to obtain the $y$, Bob is supposed to create a superposition $\sum_x | x \rangle | g(x) \rangle$. The function $g$ is 2-to-1: so after measuring the second register we get $| x \rangle+|x' \rangle$ on the first register for the 2 preimages of $g$. From this state we can obtain a new quantum state that will be used in other protocols (the adversary cannot fully describe this state since it can't invert $g$). If Bob wanted to learn one $x$ ,he could measure it... but it would destroy it.

Comment: So $y$ is a classical cipher text, but it is determined using a superposition that is still useful after the end of the protocol.